# attaching data to sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

i want to have some clients connect to a room with socket.io, then store their information into an object (like a user-list)

if they leave the channel, i want that entry to be auto-deleted.

how can i hook some "outside" information to a socket? is it possible?

example:

user named "joe" connects

```
socket.emit('joinRoom', {username: 'joe'});
```

on the server, i want to do something like

```
socket.on('joinRoom', function(msg) {
    userData.push(msg.username);    //  <-- how can i simplify/automatize this?
}
```

is there something built-in to manage users?

(the problem arises from me wanting to hook passport-user information to sockets. joe is logged in with passport, the server `req`knows that. but the socket doesn't, because there is no `req` at all)

**eventually, i want to be able to say "send a socket message to the user that is logged in as joe". if joe leaves the channel, remove him from the userlist etc**

is that possible? how would you do it? is my approach wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add properties to the socket object:

```
socket.on('joinRoom', function(msg) {
socket.username=msg.username;   
}
```

If the socket you want modify is not the transmitter you can do it through

```
io.sockets.connected[socket.id].username=msg.username
```

but you will need his id.

Comment: the id changes with every new pageload, right? (i tried something with socket ids before but noticed they varied everytime).
so this only works is there is no new pageload in between? (just to make sure i understand it correctly)
aside from that: can the properties on the socket object be read/written on both sides? ex: write name on client side, then retrieve it on server side?
thanks :)

Comment: Yes, if the socket lose the connection you will lose the data that you attach to it, and socket object on server and client are independent so that you have to do it manually

Comment: ok nice. one last thing: how can i address that specific socket?
say i have the moderator connect `on('joinMod', function(msg) {socket.userrole='mod'})`
now i want to send mod-relevant stuff only to that socket.
can/must i loop through all sockets? or can i say something like `to(sockets[userrole == 'mod'])` or something?

Comment: No, you can not do this. Your options are: loop through all sockets connected,  loop through all sockets connected only to this room `io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomname].sockets`, or if only there is one mod per room maybe you can have a hash object where the key is the roomname and the value is the socket.id like : `var obj={};  obj[roomname]=socket.id` so you could do `io.sockets.connected[ obj[roomname] ] `

Comment: thanks for this! now i have another problem. i opened another question over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088999/attaching-properties-to-sockets-across-events i would be happy if you could help again :)